# SharePoint Online : Turn on "Allowing non-owners to invite new users"

Tags: access, online

When I edit sharing options for a specific site collection, how do I turn back on the following option once I disable it by clicking **turn off sharing for non-members on all sites in this site collection** ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to site setting -> site permissions --> access request settings --> here select all the check boxes .. now you can go back and check your " turn off sharing for non-members on all sites in this site collection" would be available.